# Cordova: is there anyway to detect in Javascript whether an iOS app is built as debug or release?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm working on a Cordova iOS app where it would be very helpful for me to be able to detect if the app was built using a debug or release configuration. Specifically, I want to be able to detect if the app is being run on a device through Xcode (built using the debug configuration) or is being run on a device through ad hoc or app store distribution (built using the release configuration).

Normally in a native app I could just use

```
#ifdef DEBUG
```

but it's a Cordova app so I need some way to do it in Javascript.

I'm aware I could write a Cordova plug-in from scratch to do this, but I'm hoping there's an easier way, or that perhaps someone already wrote such a plug-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [plugin](https://github.com/ozexpert/cordova-plugin-device-meta). It should provide the information you need:

```
cordova.plugins.DeviceMeta.getDeviceMeta(function(result){
   // result.debug - Whether App is in debug mode
});
```